# Can you replace the the standard framing protocol in WCF NetTcp without re-writing the whole transport channel?

Tags: wcf, net-tcp

I want to use NetTcp but I want to use a custom framing protocol and I can't figure out where the framing is applied in the standard NetTcp stack.

I could write a whole new transport channel but that seems crazy if all I want to do is change the framing protocol.

Is it possible to do this?

I assume it would involve some hook on the channel factory or similar but I'd like to replace as little as possible.

Answer (score 1):

No you have to change transport binding element  and need to write custom  transport channel  with your framing protocol
for more help you can refer

http://winterdom.com/2007/02/writingawcftransportchannelpart2